# How to execute keycloack basic-auth example?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, basic-authentication, keycloak

I'm stuck on some of the following steps in [Keycloak's basic-auth example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/3.2.1.Final/examples/basic-auth):

1. "Build and deploy this sample's WAR file" - How do I deploy the war file?
2. "Simply change the username" - What `username`? There wasn't any username in the curl example :(

Can you help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but there is a certain amount of assumed knowledge that you seem to be missing, such as how to build a project using [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/index.html).

Comment: I know how to build a maven project, but the deployment in the server isn't explained. Also, the `username` is a puzzle.

Comment: Given the "curl [http://admin:password@localhost:8080/basicauth/service/echo?value=hello](http://admin:password@localhost:8080/basicauth/service/echo?value=hello)" command, what do you think **admin:password** might be?

Comment: @SteveC - missed that. Thanks. Any idea how to deploy the war?

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Getting+Started+Guide and https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/10.x/guide/GettingStarted.asciidoc